# Cannot set+read cookie via mail php site

Tags: php, email, cookies

I have a simple mail script. It send me the contents of a php website (my own website) via `file_get_contents('http://www.xxxx.com/xxxx.php');`

That works perfect. The only problem is: when I visit that website, it puts data in a cookie. Next time I visit that website, it displays data out of that cookie and puts new data in that cookie. Works perfect.
But when I call the url via `file_get_contents('http://www.xxxx.com/xxxx.php')` to send the website to my email, the cookie data cannot be set and not be read from the cookie. Can somebody explain that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use cURL instead. There are plenty of examples out there about using cURL for making GET requests and handle cookies. When you make a request, you need to store any cookie data you get in the response, then you need to send that cookie data back to the server. This is something you need to implement yourself. Just using `file_get_contents(....)`  (without any [stream_context](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php)) only makes a clean GET request (without any specific headers and cookie data)

Comment: Thank you very much, with cURL + CURLOPT_COOKIE I managed to fix it.

Comment: In this context, cookies are nothing but regular HTTP headers. You can certainly write the code yourself but it's probably going to be pretty boring. I suggest you find a third-party HTTP client ([Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#cookies) comes to my mind).